Selection of confounding variables in multiple linear regression with AIC, BIC, or both?
I am using multiple linear regression to control for confounding variables. I have analyzed my data using Bayesian Information Criterion. Is there an advantage to also using Akaike Information Criterion, perhaps as a robustness check? (I recognize that AIC and BIC both have their problems and limitations).

This page has extensive discussion of AIC versus BIC. Your question might be closed as a duplicate of that. It's a bit unclear what you mean by "I have analyzed my data using Bayesian Information Criterion." That raises a fear that there might have been some feature selection and a consequent risk of over- or under-fitting. You might want to edit the question to say more about your modeling process and how you included BIC in it.
